# Windows 10 Powershell - get-smbserverconfiguration - returns this even though I'm not connected to any servers

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, smb, smbclient

I am running a new (not upgrade) installation of Windows 10 Home on a desktop at home. This is my personal computer on an AT&T U-Verse connection that I pay for. When I execute the Powershell commands "get-smbserverconfiguration" and "get-smbclientconfiguration" I get the following results. My question is, should I be getting these results even if I'm not connected to any server? I am not that well informed regarding smb, so I may be overlooking something obvious, but I wanted to be sure.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Paigeorge> get-smbserverconfiguration


AnnounceComment                 :

AnnounceServer                  : False

AsynchronousCredits             : 64

AuditSmb1Access                 : False

AutoDisconnectTimeout           : 15

AutoShareServer                 : True

AutoShareWorkstation            : True

CachedOpenLimit                 : 10

DurableHandleV2TimeoutInSeconds : 180

EnableAuthenticateUserSharing   : False

EnableDownlevelTimewarp         : False

EnableForcedLogoff              : True

EnableLeasing                   : True

EnableMultiChannel              : True

EnableOplocks                   : True

EnableSecuritySignature         : False

EnableSMB1Protocol              : True

EnableSMB2Protocol              : True

EnableStrictNameChecking        : True

EncryptData                     : False

IrpStackSize                    : 15

KeepAliveTime                   : 2

MaxChannelPerSession            : 32

MaxMpxCount                     : 50

MaxSessionPerConnection         : 16384

MaxThreadsPerQueue              : 20

MaxWorkItems                    : 1

NullSessionPipes                :

NullSessionShares               :

OplockBreakWait                 : 35

PendingClientTimeoutInSeconds   : 120

RejectUnencryptedAccess         : True

RequireSecuritySignature        : False

ServerHidden                    : True

Smb2CreditsMax                  : 2048

Smb2CreditsMin                  : 128

SmbServerNameHardeningLevel     : 0

TreatHostAsStableStorage        : False

ValidateAliasNotCircular        : True

ValidateShareScope              : True

ValidateShareScopeNotAliased    : True

ValidateTargetName              : True
```

---

```
PS C:\Users\Paigeorge> get-smbclientconfiguration


ConnectionCountPerRssNetworkInterface : 4

DirectoryCacheEntriesMax              : 16

DirectoryCacheEntrySizeMax            : 65536

DirectoryCacheLifetime                : 10

DormantFileLimit                      : 1023

EnableBandwidthThrottling             : True

EnableByteRangeLockingOnReadOnlyFiles : True

EnableInsecureGuestLogons             : True

EnableLargeMtu                        : True

EnableLoadBalanceScaleOut             : True

EnableMultiChannel                    : True

EnableSecuritySignature               : True

ExtendedSessionTimeout                : 1000

FileInfoCacheEntriesMax               : 64

FileInfoCacheLifetime                 : 10

FileNotFoundCacheEntriesMax           : 128

FileNotFoundCacheLifetime             : 5

KeepConn                              : 600

MaxCmds                               : 50

MaximumConnectionCountPerServer       : 32

OplocksDisabled                       : False

RequireSecuritySignature              : False

SessionTimeout                        : 60

UseOpportunisticLocking               : True

WindowSizeThreshold                   : 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be getting results.  There are settings configured, regardless of whether you are connected to a server or not.

More info can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/06/27/the-basics-of-smb-powershell-a-feature-of-windows-server-2012-and-smb-3-0.aspx).

Comment: link is broken, can you fix it?